# Problemas para dividir una imagen en cuadrados en python

Tags: python, imagen, pillow

Estoy tratando de recortar una imagen usando python, pero no entiendo por qué este código da error:

```
imagen = PIL.Image.open("imagen-entera.jpg")
ancho = int(imagen.size[0]/8)
alto = int(imagen.size[1]/8)
for si in range (8):
    for gh in range (8):
        caja = (gh*ancho, si*alto, ancho, alto)
        print (caja)
        print ('tamaño: ' + str(imagen.size))
        region = imagen.crop(caja)
        path = 'cuadrado'+str(si*gh+gh)+'.png'
        print (path)
        region.save(path)
```

El error que da es este:

```
(0, 0, 225, 315)
tamaño: (2925, 1260)
cuadrado0.png
(225, 0, 225, 315)

tamaño: (2925, 1260)
cuadrado1.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 481, in _save
    fh = fp.fileno()
AttributeError: '_idat' object has no attribute 'fileno'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GUI.py", line 157, in <module>
    app = GUI(root)
  File "GUI.py", line 68, in __init__
    region.save(path)
  File "/home/manu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1950, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/home/manu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 823, in _save
    [("zip", (0, 0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])
  File "/home/manu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 489, in _save
    e.setimage(im.im, b)
SystemError: tile cannot extend outside image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en el calculo del area a recortar, según la documentación de [`crop()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.crop) el área se define como `box – The crop rectangle, as a (left, upper, right, lower)-tuple.`:

```
caja = (gh*ancho, si*alto, ancho, alto)
```

Aquí los parámetros `rigth`, `lower` siempre valdrán lo mismo, por lo que ocurre un error con el segundo recorte ya que las coordenadas serían inconsistentes. Lo que debemos es indicar las coordenadas relativas a cada recorte, por algo como esto:

```
caja = (gh*ancho, si*alto, (gh*ancho) + ancho, (si*alto) + alto)
```

Comment: No sé si el problema viene de que caí en un post de python2 o si me trompé pero gracias. tomé los parámetros 3 y 4 como ancho y alto y son posiciones en la grilla.